# JS to change 5 minute interval on SP list date picker to 15 minutes instead

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, datepicker

I want to change the default 5 minutes increment/interval on the OOTB Date Picker WebPart on a SP13 custom list to a longer interval (such as 15 minutes). How does one achieve this?

I am fairly new to SharePoint (and JS/JQuery) so please explain with good details so that a "noob" can understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should work in a Script Editor web part. Note that this will affect every date/time field on the screen.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id*="$DateTimeFieldDateMinutes"]').empty().append(
'<option selected="selected" value="00">00</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="45">45</option>');

});

</script>
```

Comment: Would this same code work to change the drop down for the HOUR (not just minutes) so it would read the "day starts" at 7 AM instead of 12 AM and ends at 4 PM instead of 11 PM?

Comment: It would, you just need to find the ID of the hour drop down. Use the F12 debugger to inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

The code below for your reference:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("select[id$='_$DateTimeFieldDateHours'] option").each(function(){
        var array=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","17","18","19","20","21","22","23"];
        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            if($(this).val()==array[i]){
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }
    });
    $("select[id$='_$DateTimeFieldDateMinutes'] option").each(function(){
        var array=["05","10","20","25","35","40","50","55"];
        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            if($(this).val()==array[i]){
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: OMG! Absolutely works wonderfully! So, now I plead with you to help me understand just how the code actually works - When I look at your code it appears that you are accounting for all 24 hours and 5 minute increments yet when implemented it displays only 7am to 4 pm and the minute increments are in 15-minute blocks exactly like I want. Beautiful, but perplexing!